# Abstracting away the persistence layer in GO

Tags: go, architecture, domain-driven-design, microservices

So, I'm relatively new to the world of Go programming and was wondering what the community considers to be "best practice" when attempting to abstract away the persistence layer.

In DDD this is often handled through the introduction of Repositories which exposes a set of Agreggates to an Application layer.

My concern is that I've been overly "conditioned" into thinking about these problems from the perspective of Object Oriented design and would like to explore other programming paradigms.

This will also be my first attempt at developing micro-services; which is part of the reason why I'd like to keep my design as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's one good answer to this question, multiple approaches may be good, one better from a specific point of view, and another being better from another point of view.

Just try to create an interface (not in the meaning of Go interface type) that hides DB specific behavior and types, which will leave you the option to easily switch to a new db implementation later on, given that all other parts of your code strictly access the persistent layer via this DB interface.

The DB interface should define Go model types (modeling data stored in the persistent layer), and operations on these types, e.g. load, find, save.

As an example, modeling a user:

```
package db

type ID int64

type User struct {
    ID   ID
    Name string
}

// Manager contains the operations that involve the persistence layer.
type Manager interface {
    LoadUser(id ID) (*User, error)
    SaveUser(u *User) error
    FindUsersByName(name string) ([]*User, error)
    Close() error
}
```

And you may create an implementation (or multiple ones) of the `Manager` interface. An implementation using MongoDB:

```
package mongo

import (
    "db"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
)

// manager is a db.Manager implementation that uses MongoDB
type manager struct {
    // unexported fields, e.g. MongoDB session:
    sess *mgo.Sess
}

func (m *manager) LoadUser(id db.ID) (*db.User, error) { ... }

func (m *manager) SaveUser(u *db.User) error { ... }

func (m *manager) FindUsersByName(name string) ([]*db.User, error) { ... }

func (m *manager) Close() error {
    m.sess.Close()
    return nil
}

func New(mongoURL string) (db.Manager, error) {
    // Create, initialize your manager, and return it:
    sess, err := mgo.Dial(url)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return &manager{sess: sess}, nil
}
```

A `db.Manager` instance (since it involves building a connection to a (Mongo)DB server) should be kept for as long as possible (e.g. global instance). Depending on the usage, `Manager.Copy()` and `Manager.Clone()` operations should be supported to acquire a copy or clone for short lived usage (e.g. serving an HTTP request).

Using this example: Someone somewhere has to call `mongo.New()` to acquire a value of the `db.Manager`, but from there we only have to interact with the persistence layer via the `Manager`, leaving any db specific detail to the implementation.

For example:

```
var mgr db.Manager
var err error

mgr, err = mongo.New("<mongodburl>")
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("Could not connect to db:", err)
    return
}
defer mgr.Close()

id := 123456
u, err := mgr.LoadUser(id)
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("Failed to load user [id: %v]: %v\n", id, err)
    return
}
fmt.Printf("Loaded User: %+v\n", u)
```

Comment: Isin't that the same as the repository pattern?

Comment: @plalx Yes, but nobody said it can't be applied or that it wouldn't be proper to use in Go.

Comment: "My concern is that I've been overly "conditioned" into thinking about these problems from the perspective of Object Oriented design and would like to explore other programming paradigms". In other words, the OP knows the repository pattern already, but he's looking to find other good alternatives to abstract away persistence concerns in Go.